# EmberJS Testing reset not fully reseting or async issue

Tags: testing, ember.js, tdd, qunit

If I change the order of my Ember/Qunit tests, they pass.  Why is that, or what can I do to avoid it?

**Edit:** I notice that the Qunit tests run in a more or less random order (whichever is ready first?), regardless, when TEST B follows TEST A, it is failing.

It seems that either App.reset() isn't fully resetting or there is some async issue I'm not seeing.

### spec

```
module("Integration Tests", {
  setup: function() {
    console.log('reset');
    Encompass.reset();
  }
});

test("TEST A", function() {
  visit("/workspaces").then(function() {
    ok(true);
  });
});

test("TEST B", function() {
  visit('/workspaces/1/submissions/1').then(function() {
    ok(find('li[title="Kyle Folder 1"]').length, "the folder is there");
  });
});
```

I have both versions of the test online.

- [A then B, B fails](http://mathforum.org/~amir/share/ember/bugs/reset/test/qunit.alt.html)
- [B then A, both pass](http://mathforum.org/~amir/share/ember/bugs/reset/test/qunit.html)

This is using the fixture adapter with a bunch of models (possibly not all the correct relations, but I still expect the tests to be consistent regardless of order)

Answer (score 2):

`App.reset()` resets the ember application itself, it doesn't reset Ember Model/Data.

You'll need to use `unloadAll` for Ember Data:

```
this.store.unloadAll('post');
```

For Ember Model you'll use `clearCache`:

```
App.Post.clearCache();
```

Have you tried allowing the visit to resolve before running ok on test A?

```
test("TEST A", function() {
  visit("/workspaces").then( function(){
    ok(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried unloadAll for each of the fixture models, but same results.  I'm using ember-data 1.0.0 beta3, should I try something newer?

Comment: Also noteworthy is that I'm not actually changing the model in the previous test (intentionally at least).  I'm just visiting the page and somehow the name attribute is disappearing.

Comment: What about allowing the visit to finish before continuing on (technically I think stop and start are called on the visit, and it's promise's resolution, so I don't think this would be an issue, but worth a shot)

Comment: Thanks, I uploaded the unloadAll version too/two: http://mathforum.org/~amir/share/ember/bugs/reset/test/qunit.alt2.html

Comment: Something looks funky with that folder record, it's almost like it gets stuck in the loading state and never continues to load.  Even more, I'm not sure if it's guaranteed to load when the page is rendered (aka it may be pushed into the run loop after render since it isn't technically part of the transition).  Unfortunately it would still eventually render which it never does.

Comment: FYI, there is currently a bug with the unloadAll implementation. There is a PR https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1482 to fix the issue.